# Select a row with the highest column value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How would I code a filter on an SSRS tablix to select only the highest value (of an ID number) when another value is duplicated?

```
EmpID  RecordID  Status                                                       
100       10001     OUT                                                                
101       10002     IN                                                                  
102       10003     IN                                                               
102       10004     OUT                                                               
103       10005     IN
```

I have a report that creates a dataset that may contain duplicate employee IDs. If the Employee ID is the same I want the SSRS Tablix to ONLY select the one with the Higher Record ID. The report is already written and the easiest way for me to fix this is to just add a filter to the Tablix rather than mess with the query.

If the query is easier to amend Im fine with that as well. Here is the existing code. If the EMPID appears more than once for any given employee...then only use the data row with the HID with the greater value.

What is happening is this is a web form that shows employee status for the day. If an employee submits a change or updates their schedule it actually creates a new row in the table for the week. The submission form is flawed but thats an issue for another day. I just need it to only read the last edit. HID is the incrementing value each time a new row is added.

SELECT        Absences.Type, humres.fullname, humres.res_id, Absences.StartDate, DATEADD(dd, - (DATEPART(dw, Absences.StartDate) - 2), Absences.StartDate) AS FirstDayOfWeek, Absences.FreeTextField_01 AS Monday,
Absences.FreeTextField_02 AS Tuesday, Absences.FreeTextField_03 AS Wednesday, Absences.FreeTextField_04 AS Thursday, Absences.FreeTextField_05 AS Friday, Absences.HID,
CASE WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_01 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_01 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_02 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Tuesday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_02 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_03 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Wednesday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_03 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_04 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Thursday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_04 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_05 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_05 ELSE '' END AS Status
FROM            humres LEFT OUTER JOIN
Absences ON humres.res_id = Absences.EmpID
WHERE        (humres.emp_stat = 'A') AND (humres.freefield16 = 0) AND (Absences.StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 4)) AND (NOT (humres.res_id IN (1, 248)))
AND (humres.emp_type = 'E') AND (humres.blocked = 0) AND (Absences.Type = 161) AND (CASE WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_01 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Monday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_01 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_02 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Tuesday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_02 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_03 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Wednesday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_03 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_04 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
= 'Thursday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_04 WHEN Absences.FreeTextField_05 <> 'Office' AND DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' THEN Absences.FreeTextField_05 ELSE '' END <> '')
ORDER BY FirstDayOfWeek, Absences.HID DESC

Comment: honestly, query would be so much cleaner and easier to implement

Comment: You can use my answer below as a template , just add the 'INTO #t' just before the `FROM` then adjust the subsequent query to match your actual fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much more work doing it in SSRS.

To do this in SSRS you would have to group by EmpID and then get MAX(RecordID), then you would have to do a `LOOKUP` back to the same dataset using a combined key of EmpID and MAX(RecordID) to get the Status that matches the last one. Messy and hard to debug.

In SQL it's a pretty trivial task. If the current query is complex then you can always get the result of this and then process it further, all within the dataset query.

So, if a simple version of your current query looks like this...

```
SELECT 
        EmpID, RecordID, Status
    FROM myTable
```

You can just dump the results into a temp table and then process further

```
SELECT 
        EmpID, RecordID, Status
INTO #t 
    FROM myTable

SELECT EmpID, RecordID, Status
    FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY RecordID DESC) as RowN  FROM #t
        ) r 
    WHERE r.RowN = 1
```

This will give you the desired results